Use 3, single phase transformers, to lower 208 v 3 phase to 24 v 3 phase, possible or bad idea; see drawing
I want to use my 208 volt three phase to run a 3 phase, 24 volt motor.
I wanted to know if I can step down my three  phase 208 voltage, to three 24 volt transformers,(each getting one phase) to step down each phase of the three phase to the 24 three phase voltage I need.
See attached drawing.  Thank you for confirmation of this scheme, or warning and information on why this is not a good idea i.e., why this will not work?
Thank you for your review and comments.

You didn't attach the "attached drawing".

I did when I started the post, musta got lost, can I add one now? how to do that please?

Click the "edit" button. After uploading the picture, don't forget to click the "add picture" button.

Thank you , added image should now be there

Since your transformer primaries are connected between phase and Neutral, I think you will want 120:24V transformers, not 208:24V.  208 V is normally between phases, with 120 V phase to neutral.

To add to @PeterBennett, if you already have the transformers wound for 208 V, you need to connect them in delta.

Hi Peter, Good call on using the 120 tap instead of the 208 tap will do.

Something similar applies to secondary voltage: connecting the secondaries "in delta", check whether the 24 V spec for the motor is star or delta.

Thank you, that  is an important point I will checkout.

because the transformers on both sides are star connected it will work and produce 24VAC from 208VAC  even though the transformers themselves are seeing a lower voltage.  switching both sides to delta connections would get you more available current.

Thank you Jasen
